# Word crashes when printing

Tags: random, printing, crash, papercut

I've been looking for a Solution for 3 month now.

I'm using Papercut server for printing and it always worked with no problem.

Since we upgrade all computers to windows 11, Users have problem to print specifically with Word (office 2016).

When they try to print, Word just crashes and they have to shut it down through task manager. but it happens only with papercut network printer and it does not happen every time, it seems random.

If someone has a good idea to resolve this, it would be really apreciated.

thx

We already tried to repair / reinstall / update office, use safe mode, deactivate add-ons, but nothing changed.

we also tried to change the drivers, reinstall papercut, change papercut settings, no effect..

We also tried to apply "rpc on named pipes" GPO on all computers and also tried

localy by modifying registry keys, no results...